# Adding data to a hashmap in parallel

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++11, parallel-processing

I've got an instance of an std::unordered_map serving as a database of some sort. (It's basically just a regular hashmap).
I have 4 threads retrieving long strings from a network (I'm using the c++11 std::threads) and within each of those threads, i tokenize the strings they receive. The tokenization itself is paralellized as well using the new Microsoft AMP library (so the process of tokenization is done by the GPU threads).

I would like each of the 4 "main" threads to add the tokens as keys into the hashmap as the GPU threads finish tokenizing the strings (and then repeat the process).

How would i go about synchronizing all of this so that i can safely add new keys into my database from each of the threads ?

Comment: Have a `std::mutex` at the same scope as your `std::unordered_map<>` and have each thread lock the mutex before touching the hash table. Honestly, though, if you're concerned about throughput, you'd probably be better off with a proper concurrent container rather than a manually synchronized one.

Comment: It's probably more efficient to have one hashmap per thread and then merge them pairwise concurrently as you finish up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use concurrent_unordered_map instead of unordered_map in [concurrent_unordered_map.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750089%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Why thank you fine sir, you've just saved me hours of boring work.